# Calling models with _ us controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table in the model called pg_search_documents, how do I work with it in the controllers?

I'm trying like this:

```
def show
  @search = PgSearchDocument.find(params[:content])
end
```

But the so-called "PgSearchDocument" seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you have a model declared in your app.  If you have not done so, create the following file:

`app/models/pg_search_document.rb`

```
class PgSearchDocument < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

In Rails 5 you would use:

```
class PgSearchDocument < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Please note the following naming conventions in Rails:

- Database table name is plural snake case: `pg_search_documents`
- Model filename is singular snake case: `pg_search_document.rb`
- Model class name is singular camel case: `PgSearchDocument`